# Accesing tags with beautiful soup and css

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, tags

I need to obtain the fields "Ubicación" and "Valoración 5 de 5".

I have the following code in Python but it doesn't print out anything. Could you help me please?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url=input("Introduce url: ")
req=urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
html=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for puntuacion in soup:
    if soup("span",{"class":"_fgdupie"})=="Ubicacion":
        print(soup.find_all("span",{"class":"_1iu38l3"}))
```

[image]

Comment: please provide code, not images and allow an example of code that one can replicate. you can omit input() and post html =...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Provide a code sample of the HTML and not an image. That will be easier for people to help you with.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the URL, that way we could reproduce your problem.